# SSAS OLAP - Group the member of different dimension under one Group

Tags: olap-cube, ssas-2012

I have an SSAS OLAP cube with 3 product ids in FACT ie. ProductID, EndProductID, ChildProductID and related to same Dimension Product to give me 3 Dimensions in Cube as Product, EndProduct and ChildProduct. Is there a Way in SSAS to group the Product Names and bring it under One Umbrella of say Product and show the attributes under Product as Product, End product and Child product.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Displayfolder attribute in each dimension and group them like that. You will still have 3 individual dimensions visible, but they will all be under one folder.